# Why is it non-trivial to write mathematics on the web?

Tags: web, markup

I wanted to write a readable fraction with html and found it [non-trivial](https://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/e9wd6Lfq/) and not portable. Why is it not very easy to write mathematical formulas with html and why has it taken so long to include simple mathematical expressions in html? I could think that it should be easy to write a fraction with a straight line between denominator and nominator.

Is it a technical difficulty to include mathematical expression in "native" html and that's why we must use external libraries (e.g. mathjax), is it that TeX is preferred by mathematicians and that TeX is complicated, or is it for some other reason, maybe som principle that html shouldn't be able to generate simple mathematical expressions such as fraction bar?

Comment: recommended reading: **[On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)**

Comment: Actually today most math is typeset with LaTeX, not with plain TeX.

Comment: Cat videos are a lot more popular than math formulae, but not even those are fully stanardised across Browsers. The HTML sure is, but the used codecs are not. It seems like browser vendors simply can't or more likely don't want to get their s..t together in terms of compatibility.

Comment: MathML is part of HTML5, but (1) authoring MathML by hand is challenging, and (2) [none of the popular browsers except Firefox and Safari implement MathML](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mathml) in their rendering engines since this adds a lot of complexity. Since nearly all STEM papers are written in LaTeX, tools like MathJax not only add cross-browser compatibility, but also a more convenient user interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematical formulas (or formulae) can be viewed as some language (difficult to write or typeset or display in a pretty way).

The original [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) was not designed (in the early 1990s) with that language in mind (nor was it designed for non European languages like Chinese or Arabic, nor for chemistry formulas, nor for music). [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) appeared before HTML.

Current web standards are much more complex. Study [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) & [MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML). Notice that not all web browsers [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mathml) them in full (as commented by [amom](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/60357/amon)).

<sup>(economically, few people care about math formulas on the Web today, so there might not be enough incentive to support them very well)</sup>

You might be interested in tools converting LaTeX to HTML, such as [HeVeA](http://hevea.inria.fr/).

<sup>PS. Regarding your title `Why is it non-trivial to write mathematics on the web?` (opinion-based!), I don't believe that writing complex formulas with LaTeX is trivial. At least it is *not trivial for me*, when I have to write complex formulas.</sup>

Comment: Note: I am not sure of the spelling in plural of *formula*. Is it the latin *formulae* or should it be *formulas*?

Comment: 'Formulas' is the common/ubiquitous mistake that is not only acceptable but also in the process of becoming the norm (if it isn't already); the correct 'formulae' will eventually be decreed erroneous. It's the way all languages are going, but in English it's especially pronounced with Latin-derived plurals. My pet hates are things like 'a criteria', 'an insignia' (or 'a bacteria' - from a graduated microbiologist no less); 'a visa' has already been the norm for ages..

Comment: @DarthGizka: So should I replace `formulae` with `formulas` in my answer?; bear with me, since I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: Either spelling is perfectly all right, although 'formulae' has a slight whiff of academia nowadays. Outside of academic contexts I'd use the modern, regularised 'formulas'.

Comment: "economically, few people care about math formulas on the Web today, so there might not be enough incentive to support them very well". And that is the objective answer to this question, right there.